# clearInterval don't work, counter continue

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I use this portion of code in a REACTjs function component, my counter starts fine, but the clearInterval has no effect, it still counts... I checked with "console.log" that each line of this code is called at the desired time. The store is managed by redux toolkit.
"startCounter" just spins a mini animation indicating that the counter is running. Thank you for your attention.

```js
// Start = starter -> true 
// Stop = starter -> False
function setTimer (starter) {
    let interv = setInterval(setClock, 1000);
    setStartCounter(true);`
    if (!starter) {`
        clearInterval(interv);
        setStartCounter(false);    `
    }
}
function setClock () {`
    dispatch(toggleTimeCountTask(task.id));`
}
```

The "interv" variable is declared and used only in this function, I went through some similar topics, but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: How exactly is this related to React?  What calls `setTimer`?  Is it being called multiple times?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Looking at `setTimer` a bit closer... Why create an interval only to *immediately* clear it in the first place?  If `starter` is `false`, why not just return immediately and not bother creating an interval that you don't want to use?  And if `starter` is `true` then nothing ever clears that interval anyway, by design.  The logic of this function doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: onClick={setTimer(true)} starts the timer, onClick={setTimer(false)} should stop it, these are HTML buttons

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating the `setInterval` inside your function. So two executions will result in two timers. You should move it outside the function as so:

```
const interv = useRef(null);

function setTimer (starter) {
    if(!interv.current) {
        interv.current = setInterval(setClock, 1000);
    }
    setStartCounter(true);
    if (!starter) {
        clearInterval(interv.current);
        setStartCounter(false);
        interv.current = null;
    }
}
function setClock () {
    dispatch(toggleTimeCountTask(task.id));
}
```

If this is inside a functional component, you need to cleanup if the component is destroyed:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        if(interv.current) {
            clearInterval(interv.current);
        }
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks,I have already tried, the counter speeds up as if it counts faster and faster. I feel like it instantiates multiple times, but why??

Comment: Unless this is happening within a React component.  In which case `interv` will be `null` on every render and state updates will trigger a re-render, resulting in an infinite series of intervals.

Comment: Updated with useRef to allow timer instance to persist for lifetime of component.

Comment: This version has a guard to prevent second timers, it only creates a new timer if the current timer is null.

Comment: It's great, thanks Gunwin, it works perfectly. It was indeed useRef that I was missing